# Why can't Thunderbird decrypt messages made with Kleopatra?

Tags: thunderbird, kleopatra

So if I import a public key made by thunderbird into Kleopatra and use it to encrypt a message, then send an email containing that message, thunderbird gives an error and doesn't decrypt the message.

Comment: public keys encrypt, private keys decrypt. did you add the private key to Thunderbird as well?

Comment: @FrankThomas the key pair was made in thunderbird in the first place, so yes it does have the private key.